# Recompose "withReducer": justification of async reducer function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recompose

I'm using withReducer HOC and noticed this behaviour:
Calling this on click handler for example:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { withReducer } from 'recompose'
import { compose } from 'ramda'

export default compose(
  withReducer('state', 'dispatch', (state, { value }) => {
    console.log(value)
    return { ...state, value }
  }, { value: 'zero' })
)((props) => {
  const { dispatch, state } = props,
    onClick = () => {
      console.log('Hello')
      dispatch({ value: 'one' })
      dispatch({ value: 'two' })
      dispatch({ value: 'three' })
      console.log('World')
    }
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{state.value}</div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  )
})
```

It will produce

> Hello
>
> World
>
> one
>
> two
>
> three

This means that reduce function is called asynchronously.
What is justification for calling it async rather than applying changes to store right away?

Answer (score 4):

The reducer is called asynchronously because we can only use `setState` to update the tree and `setState` is asynchronous.

If we call the reducer synchronously, we will need to save the new state somewhere, then call `setState` and get the new state asynchronously from where we save it. In the end, your tree still get updated asynchronously.

This is why recompose's `withReducer()` is slightly different from redux. You can think of that `withReducer` is a simplified version of redux + react-redux's `connect()`.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, dispatch is actually a wrapper for the vanilla API method `setState`.

React implements `setState` asynchronously because state transitions are sometimes batched together for performance reasons.

According to the React [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition....There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.